# security issue IIS7.5 / IIS APPPOOL\user not authorized but has full control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis-7.5

It seems I have a strange issue with security:

I have a website with the following folders:

- inetpub\wwwroot
- inetpub\wwwroot\readyfordownload

The IIS APPPOOL\Classic user has full access to this 'readyfordownload' folder.

Now I have a console APP that creates a zipfile in the readyfordownload folder. This is done from a c# classlib. Strangely enough, the IIS APPOOL cannot access this file, even though it has full control over the folder. Also, the classlib first creates an xlsx file that is later added to the zip. The APPPOOL user does have access to the xlsx file.

If I run the same function in the C# classlib from a code behind in the website, the same zipfile is created and the IIS APPPOOL user CAN access the file....

Any ideas?

zip is created like this (not the actual code, but it is the same)
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

```
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
             zip.AddFile("test.xlsx");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
```

}

OS is windows 2008 R2 web server
ZIP library  is Dotnetzip (Ionic)

**Update: I am most interested in why the ZIPfile does not get the rights and the xlsx file does....**

Comment: Have you inspected the permissions of the file that you cannot access?  I agree with scottm that most likely the file did not inherit the permissions from the parent folder.

Comment: But why would the XLSX file that is generated inherit the permissions and the ZIP file not?

Comment: how are you creating the zip file?  Can you show us the code that generates it?  (for example, a file copy would *not* inherit the permissions of the destination folder)

Comment: see updated post. It is not a copy. Strangely enough the xlsx is created from a template file and the template file is copied...

Comment: For others who get this error it might be worth noting that if a file with exactly the same filename already exists in the destination folder, this will also throw the same/a similar error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried setting the [FileAccessSecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d49cww7f.aspx) explicitly? Maybe the files are not inheriting the ACL from the directory.

Comment: yes, that is my workaround but I do not understand why the zipfile does not inherit them but the XLSX file does. They are generated in the same function (the xlsx file is very big, that is why it is being zipped)

Comment: @Pleun, you would need to look into the internals of the ZIP library you are using to find out how the ACL is being applied when the .zip is created.

Comment: mmmhh... not sure if I want to. With the workaround it is working in the end so I am not going to bother that much. Was hoping there was some obvious solution. Will post in their forum, I think. Thanx. Will credit your answer for the bounty unless some magical solution occurs.

Answer (score 2):

the apppool user can access the xlsx file because your console creates it directly under readyfordownload folder.

the zip file on the other hand is first created in a temp folder and then copied to your folder. This means that the file permissions are wrongly set on the file.

1. Make sure IIS_IUSR and DefaultAppPool users have access on your wwwroot.
2. As scottm suggested change your console code to give permissions to the IUSR and DefaultAppPool users on the zip file. Your code should read like:

   ```
       using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
       {
           // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
           zip.AddFile("test.xlsx");
           zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");

           var accessControl = File.GetAccessControl("MyZipFile.zip");

           var fileSystemAccessRule = new FileSystemAccessRule(
                                       @"BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS",
                                       FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                                       AccessControlType.Allow);

           var fileSystemAccessRule2 = new FileSystemAccessRule(
                                       @"IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool",
                                       FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute,
                                       AccessControlType.Allow);

           accessControl.AddAccessRule(fileSystemAccessRule);
           accessControl.AddAccessRule(fileSystemAccessRule2);

           File.SetAccessControl(path, accessControl);
       }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check Windows EventLog for related errors. For detailed info use [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), so you can see if there is a problem with permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the security of the folder using “advanced securty setting property page”. (Select properties--> security). Also note that the application pool can impersonate the user so that the application may not be serving the request with the identity of the app pool. By default impersonation may not work. You have to set it explicitly in the web config. E.g. `<identity impersonate="true" />` or `<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="password" />`

Sriwantha Sri Aravinda

Comment: sorry, valid points (all checked) but this does not address the difference between the zipfile and the xlsx file...